# Update global state after RTK Query loads data

Tags: redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I've noticed a problem with splitting responsibilities in React components based on the fetched data using RTK Query.

Basically, I have two components like `HomePage` and `NavigationComponent`.
On `HomePage` I'd like to fetch the information about the user so that I can modify `NavigationComponent` accordingly.

What I do inside `HomePage`:

```js
import { setNavigationMode } from "features/nav/navSlice";

export default function HomePage() {
  const {data: user} = useGetUserDataQuery();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const navMode = user ? "all-options" : "none";

  dispatch(setNavigationMode(navMode)); // here I change the default Navigation mode

  return <MainLayout>
    <Navigation/>
    <Content/>
    <Footer/>
  </MainLayout>;
}
```

The `HomePage` is a special Page when the `NavigationComponent` shouldn't display any options for the not logged-in user.
Other pages present additional `Logo` and `Title` on `Nav`.

React communicates:

> Warning: Cannot update a component (`NavComponent`) while rendering a different component (`HomePage`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `HomePage`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render

Not sure what is the right way to follow.
Whether the state should be changed in the GetUser query after it is loaded - that doesn't seem to be legit.

Comment: please provide more information. and use `{}` instead of `[]` for ```useGetUserDataQuery```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was too obvious. The dispatch should be run in `useEffect`.

```js
import { setNavigationMode } from "features/nav/navSlice";

export default function HomePage() {
  const {data: user} = useGetUserDataQuery();
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const navMode = user ? "all-options" : "none";

  // changed lines
  useEffect( () => {
    dispatch(setNavMode(navMode));
  }, [navMode, dispatch]);
  // /changed lines

  return <MainLayout>
    <Navigation/>
    <Content/>
    <Footer/>
  </MainLayout>;
}
```

Thank you @papa-xvii for the hint with changing the `navMode` after user `login`. That solves the second problem I had.
However I cannot accept the answer as it does not solve the problem I described above.

Answer (score 2):

problem is `dispatch` calls every render. Instead you can create a `navigationSlice` (if you don't have already) and use `extraReducers` for matching your authorization action like:

```
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      usersApi.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
      (state, { payload }) => {
        if (payload.user) {              
          state.navigationMode = "all-options"
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

This way, `state.navigationMode` will only change when authorization changes

Comment: Good point, I added that implementation into my `navSlice` and it works really well.
However it hasn't solve the problem yet. The `HomePage` still cannot override the `navMode` in render mode.

Comment: glad it helped. this just covers login.matchFulfilled, you probably have other authorization methods, like load user from token, so you need to add matcher for them as well